# Insert data into one table and update another

Tags: php, insert

I have 2 different tables `project` and `payments`. When I insert a payment I want the value of `flag` from the `project` table to be changed to `paid` if the `$money inserted` are exactly the same as the value of `cost` (`cost` is another cell from the `project` table) and the `$order = proj_name`.

Here comes the code!

```
 <?php
 include("connect.php");
 // define variables
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $order = $_POST['order'];
 $money = $_POST['money'];
 $date = $_POST['date'];

 $sql="INSERT INTO payments VALUES
 ('','$name','$order','$money','$date')";

 $s="UPDATE project SET flag='payed' WHERE proj_name='$order' AND cost like '%money%'";
 mysql_query($s);
 echo '<center>' ."Payment stored successfully". '</center>';
 echo '<center>'."<a href='payments_edit.php'>View Changes</a>".'</center>';

 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_close();?>
```

If you want any more info on anything let me know :)

Comment: What's actual question? By the way, I feel sql injection.

Comment: dont mind the injection.. its for a project at university :P the actual question is that nothing happens when lets say the order costs 500$ and i isnert 500$ ... while i want the value of flag to change to payed and not stay pending if i insert the exact value!

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `$` in `AND cost like '%money%'`. It should be `AND cost like '%$money%'`

Comment: and i was staring at the monitor for hours to see whats been missing :S TY ALL